# How to force the CMake that write a file after executing each line instead of creating it at last?

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a CMakeList for big projects with many libraries. this CMakeList appends these small projects with add_subdirectory like:

```
add_subdirectory(a)
add_subdirectory(b)
```

Each subdirectory has multiple static libraries. libraries of `b` directories depend on libraries of `a` directories. I implementing the function for finding libraries like bellow:

```
if (TARGET ${FINDING_NAME})
    get_target_property(BINARY_DIR ${FINDING_NAME} BINARY_DIR}
    find_library(FINDING_LIBRARY_PATH
        NAMES ${LIBRARY_NAME}
        HINTS ${BINARY_DIR})
    list(APPEND ${DEPENDENCIES_LIST} ${FINDING_LIBRARY_PATH})
else()
    find_library(FINDING_LIBRARY_PATH
        NAMES ${LIBRARY_NAME})

    list(APPEND ${DEPENDENCIES_LIST} ${FINDING_LIBRARY_PATH})
endif()
```

unfortunately, When executing the Cmake for the first time all Dependencies find in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib`. I expect to find for example `project_dir/Release/a/...` but when I execute the Cmake for the second time, the Dependencies are found in `project_dir/Release/a/...`.

I think Cmake generates the `.a` file at the last but I need these `.a` at the middle(when calling `add_library()`).

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: `Cmake generates the .a file` so don't use `find_library`, if the library is not there.

Comment: In some scenario I want to build for example `b` directory individually and in this scenario only should find from `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib` so need `find_library`

Comment: ? So in this scenario use `find_library`. In the other don't. Or, becuase `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib` should already be inside `ld.conf`, just `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: this function is a general approach for many libraries such as external libraries and internal libraries and each module call this function for find dependencies. my issue about Why Cmake could not generate the `.a` file after calling `add_library` and making these files at the last.

Comment: `Why Cmake could not generate the .a file after calling add_library and making these files at the last.`  You have to show your CMakeLists to answer such specific questions. Most probably, because you are linking with specific `.so` files, not with a target, cmake is not aware of the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your `find_library` code and link with the libraries you need to:

```
target_link_libraries(thetarget a)
```

If the target `a` exists, the target will be used for linking.

If the library is installed to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib`, then `-la` will make the compiler find the library `liba.a` from the standard `ld.so.conf` search paths.

If the library is not installed and the target does not exist, linker will inform you of a missing library.

`find_library` is for searching a library *from a very specific path*, no need to use it if you are searching for a library in compiler standard search paths (and you are not handling cases when the library is not found). Linker is for finding libraries, no need to use CMake for it.